# Array of pointers, VirtualAlloc and RtlMoveMemory. MASM, some kind of problem

Tags: pointers, assembly, winapi, x86, masm32

Does anybody know how to fix the addElement function so it ends up as another element in the array.  The idea is a dynamic array, where arrayPtr is a pointer to the first element, then new elements can be added dynamically and kept track of by increasing the arrayPtr value.  So in-fact I think what it would end up being is an array of pointers to DbRecord structs in memory.  Allocated by VirtualAlloc and copied by RtlMoveMemory.  I am kinda of hung up on RtlMoveMemeory line.  I feel like my line of thinking is correct.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

addElement PROTO: ptr DbRecord

.data?
    DbRecord struct
        Id      dd  ?
        WordOne     db 32   dup(?) ; db is define byte, set value of byte
        WordTwo     db 32   dup(?)
        WordThree   db 32   dup(?)
        Year        dd  ?
    DbRecord ends

    arrayPtr dd ?       ; pointer in memory to start of array
    newElementPointer DbRecord <>
    hStdOut dd ?
    bytesWritten dd ?

.data
    arrayCount dd 0
    hello db 'Hello World!', 0

.code
main proc
    LOCAL DbRecord01:DbRecord
    mov [DbRecord01.Id], 1;

    ; any other way than one character at a time?
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne], 'D'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 1], 'o'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 2], 'g'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo], 'C'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 1], 'a'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 2], 't'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree], 'E'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 1], 'y'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 2], 'e'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 3], 0

    mov [DbRecord01.Year], 2022;

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov [hStdOut], eax

    invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, offset hello, sizeof hello, offset bytesWritten, NULL
    invoke addElement, addr DbRecord01

    ret
main endp

addElement proc DbRecordPointer: ptr DbRecord
    invoke VirtualAlloc, NULL, sizeof DbRecord, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE  ; I beleive store a memory address in eax
    invoke RtlMoveMemory, DbRecord ptr [eax], DbRecordPointer, sizeof DbRecord ; but how to use that memory address here?
    ret
addElement endp

end main
```

EDIT/Update:
So yes part of the answer is just passing in eax.

I am here now
How do I get the value of eax ("memory location from VirtualAlloc",) where data was copied into arrayPtr (arrayPtr + count * sizeof DbRecord)

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

addElement PROTO: ptr DbRecord

.data?
    DbRecord struct
        Id      dd  ?
        WordOne     db 32   dup(?) ; db is define byte, set value of byte
        WordTwo     db 32   dup(?)
        WordThree   db 32   dup(?)
        Year        dd  ?
    DbRecord ends

    arrayPtr dword ?        ; pointer in memory to start of array
;   newElementPointer DbRecord <>
    hStdOut dd ?
    bytesWritten dd ?

.data
    arrayCount dd 0
    hello db 'Hello World!', 0

.code
main proc
    LOCAL DbRecord01:DbRecord
    mov [DbRecord01.Id], 1;

    ; any other way than one character at a time?
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne], 'D'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 1], 'o'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 2], 'g'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordOne + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo], 'C'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 1], 'a'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 2], 't'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordTwo + 3], 0

    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree], 'E'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 1], 'y'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 2], 'e'
    mov byte ptr [DbRecord01.WordThree + 3], 0

    mov [DbRecord01.Year], 2022;

    invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov [hStdOut], eax

    invoke WriteConsole, hStdOut, offset hello, sizeof hello, offset bytesWritten, NULL
    invoke addElement, addr DbRecord01

    ret
main endp

addElement proc uses edx DbRecordPointer: ptr DbRecord
    Local newElementPointer: Dword
    invoke VirtualAlloc, NULL, sizeof DbRecord, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE  ; I beleive store a memory address in eax
    mov newElementPointer, eax

    ;invoke RtlMoveMemory, newElementPointer , DbRecordPointer, sizeof DbRecord ; but how to use that memory address here?
    invoke RtlMoveMemory, eax , DbRecordPointer, sizeof DbRecord
    mov edx, arrayCount
    inc edx
    mov arrayCount, edx
    ;mov dword ptr [arrayPtr+arrayCount], eax

    ret
addElement endp

end main
```

Comment: Maybe you just want `eax` without brackets, but you did not say whether you get a compile or run time error and what the problem is exactly.

Comment: INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 1 on the RtlMoveMemory line

Comment: Did you try just passing `eax`?

Comment: I updated the edit, with that change, you are correct, but there was still a small thing I am not clear on.

Comment: Pointers are 4 bytes, so you'd need to scale by 4. However you do not even have an array.

Comment: Would that not be the arrayPtr, but I guess I have to make that global a array of a predefined size, 512 records for example I would need``` arrayPtr dword 512 dup(?)```

Comment: Yes that would work and then you should do `mov dword ptr [arrayPtr+4*edx], eax` (before incrementing `edx`).

Comment: thanks, going to print them out next.